# Bulk remove components of query string from URLs

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to convert the following mySQL query to a fast PHP solution.
The variable here is `$url` and what I want is to remove everything that starts with the following strings, including them.

For example

```
domain.com/foo/bar?gcllid=abcdefghi
```

should be

```
domain.com/foo/bar
```

Here is the query

```
UPDATE browsing SET url = SUBSTRING_INDEX( url ,'?gclid',1), 
url = SUBSTRING_INDEX( url ,'&gclid',1), 
url = SUBSTRING_INDEX( url ,'?fbclid',1), 
url = SUBSTRING_INDEX( url ,'&utm_source',1),
url = SUBSTRING_INDEX( url ,'?utm_campaign',1),
url = SUBSTRING_INDEX( url ,'?utm_medium',1),
url = SUBSTRING_INDEX( url ,'?token',1),
url = SUBSTRING_INDEX( url ,'&fbclid',1),
url = SUBSTRING_INDEX( url ,'&utm_campaign',1),
url = SUBSTRING_INDEX( url ,'&utm_medium',1),
url = SUBSTRING_INDEX( url ,'&token',1);
```

Comment: Surely you can read about regular expressions or [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Honestly it sounds like you just want to strip everything past the `?`.

Comment: @tadman No, because there are several cases like `domain.com/?results=abc` that are needed

Comment: You'll need a [proper URI parser](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.parse-url.php) to manipulate that string without utterly trashing it then.

Comment: @tadman what about a str_replace ?

Comment: That will come close, but runs the risk of turning `/foo/bar?x=y&z=a` into `/foo/bar&z=a` which is not a valid query string. Use the URI parser, manipulate the query string as necessary, re-encode.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this little function I made... \(o.0)/

```
$remove = ["foo"];
$url = 'domain.com/foo/bar?gcllid=abcdefghi&foo=bar';

function f($u,array$r){$x='?';if(!strpos($u,$x))return$u;parse_str(parse_url($u,6),$g);return rtrim(substr_replace($u,http_build_query(array_diff_key($g,array_flip($r))),strpos($u,$x)+1),$x);}




echo f($url,$remove);
```

Output

```
domain.com/foo/bar?gcllid=abcdefghi
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0117935bce7e6457b429d3405d4bf76014f955a8)

As shown above whatever "keys" (case sensitive) are in `$remove` are remove'd.  They are not just "stripped" out in a crude fashion.  But instead, this uses a combination of these functions:

- `parse_url` - for getting the query string from a url
- `parse_str` - for parsing query string to array
- `http_build_query` - for rebuilding the query string from an array

There are a few of my other favorite functions mixed in there like `substr_replace`, `rtrim`, `array_diff_key`, `array_flip` and the ever present `strpos`.

It should go without saying, but you can put as many `keys` in the `$remove` list as you want. It also properly handles URL's missing the `?` query string, by just returning them. It will remove the `?` if its the only thing left of the query string so no trailing `?`.

For your example, from the question:

> For example
>
> `domain.com/foo/bar?gcllid=abcdefghi`
>
> should be
>
> `domain.com/foo/bar`

You just use these inputs:

```
$remove = ["gcllid"];
$url = 'domain.com/foo/bar?gcllid=abcdefghi';
```

And you get this output

```
domain.com/foo/bar
```

Cheers!

***PS** you may want to rename it something other then `f`...

Answer (score 0):

Get all parts of the URL, parse the query string and get the difference between that and the ones you want to delete and rebuild:

```
$delete = ['gclid', 'fbclid']; //add the rest to delete
$vars = parse_url($url);
parse_str($vars['query'], $output);
$new = array_key_diff($output, $delete);
$url = $vars['scheme'].$vars['host'].$vars['path'].'?'.implode('&', $new);
```

This is an example, you might want to add the `port`, `user` etc. parts as well.  Also, you might use `http_build_query` instead of `implode` on the URL to encode the values.